# What is the difference between plotstyle=curve and plotpoints=1000?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

The first code:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\m{1/((x-1)^2)^(1/3)}

\begin{document}    
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(3.5,3.5)
 \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{->}(0,0)(3,3)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
 \psplot[ algebraic,
         % plotstyle=curve,
            plotpoints=1000, <<-- notice
            yMaxValue=3,
            linewidth=1.5pt,
            linecolor=red]{0}{3}{\m}
\psline[linestyle=dashed](1,0)(1,3)
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

The second code:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\m{1/((x-1)^2)^(1/3)}

\begin{document}    
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(3.5,3.5)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{->}(0,0)(3,3)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
\psplot[ algebraic,
         plotstyle=curve,
         %plotpoints=1000,
          yMaxValue=3,
         linewidth=1.5pt,
         linecolor=red]{0}{3}{\m}
\psline[linestyle=dashed](1,0)(1,3)
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

The result of compiling is frustrating.

1. What is the difference between them?
2. Can you fix the picture to make it become equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to explain is showing the animations, right?

## With `curve` plotstyle

It needs at least 3 points. When `N=2` there is no graph.

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\m{1/((x-1)^2)^(1/3)}
\def\xl{3 -1.5 exp neg 1 add}
\def\xr{3 -1.5 exp 1 add}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=2+1}{20}{%
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic,showpoints,plotstyle=curve](-1,-1)(3.5,4)
    \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{->}(0,0)(3,3.5)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
    \psplot[linecolor=red,plotpoints=\i]{0}{\xl}{\m}
    \psplot[linecolor=red,plotpoints=\i]{\xr}{3}{\m}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](1,0)(1,3)
    \rput[t](2,3){$N=\i$}
\end{pspicture}} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

## With `line` plotstyle

It needs at least 2 points.

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\m{1/((x-1)^2)^(1/3)}
\def\xl{3 -1.5 exp neg 1 add}
\def\xr{3 -1.5 exp 1 add}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=2+1}{20}{%
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic,showpoints,plotstyle=line](-1,-1)(3.5,4)
    \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{->}(0,0)(3,3.5)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
    \psplot[linecolor=red,plotpoints=\i]{0}{\xl}{\m}
    \psplot[linecolor=red,plotpoints=\i]{\xr}{3}{\m}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](1,0)(1,3)
    \rput[t](2,3){$N=\i$}
\end{pspicture}} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Final output

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\m{1/((x-1)^2)^(1/3)}
\def\xl{3 -1.5 exp neg 1 add}
\def\xr{3 -1.5 exp 1 add}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-.5,-.6)(4,4)
    \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{->}(0,0)(3.5,3.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{\xl}{\m}
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{\xr}{3}{\m}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](1,0)(1,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## My best practices

- Split the graph into two or more invocation of `\psplot` when there are discontinuities in a single plot.
- Increasing `plotpoints` blindly will waste more storage because  the size of PDF (or SVG) increases as well.
- You don't need to change `plotstyle` most of the time.

## Explanation

- `\def\xl{3 -1.5 exp neg 1 add}` is the value of `xl<1` such that `f(xl)=3`.
- `\def\xr{3 -1.5 exp 1 add}` is the value of `xr>1` such that `f(xr)=3`.
- `plotstyle` represents the type of curves is used to connect points.
- `plotpoints` represents the number of points used to draw the curve.

Comment: Many compliments too for the animations.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}    

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(3.5,3.5)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{->}(0,0)(3,3)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
\psclip{\psframe[linestyle=none](3,3)}
  \psplot[ algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red]{0}{3}{1/((x-1)^2)^(1/3)}
\endpsclip
\psline[linestyle=dashed](1,0)(1,3)
\end{pspicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the difference between them (my title) to me ? Herbert !

Comment: All curves are plotted by connecting points. With setting `yMaxValue` you have an internal `if y > yMaxValue then do not plot`. It depends to the number of points how near do you get with the calculated point to the maximal value.  With clipping you have exactly the same y value. With `plotpoints=5000` they are also nearly the same.

Comment: So, when should we use plotstyle replace plotpoints and opposite?

Comment: `plotstyle=curve` or `bezier` only for curves with continuous bends and plotpoints > 100. `plotstyle=line` for a lot of plotpoints and a curve which has not too  big slopes. Howver, for plotpoints > 1000 it doesn't really matter which plotstyle do you use.

Comment: Why we use plotpoints > 500 will make file size bigger than plotstyle?

Comment: It is not a question of file size, it is a question of the curve what will be the best setting! `y=x^2` is far different to something like `y= sin(x)/x`. For thefirst one you can use the deafult setting and any plotstyle you like. For the latter it depends to the domain if you are near `x=0` or far away from the origin. Compare http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-plot/FunctionExamples#oscillo

Comment: Yes, I will think about it. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: btw: I meant `y= sin(1/x)` the oscillator function